# is it possible to float half of the text on the right in option list?

Tags: php, html, css

I don't know if it is possible ...
But basically in my drop down list i want to have something of the sort:

> [$value_________________$value] _ = space

Hope that is clear enough ... i know how to make the whole text go to the right but just wondering if there is a trick or something idk.

Currently my code is below:

```
  <select name="lesson_type" id="lesson_type">
     <option value=""  disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a module type.</option>
     <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['module_code'];?>">
                           <?php echo $row['module_name'];
                                 echo $row['module_code'];?>
            <option>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
  </select><br />
```

Comment: Not possible via regular HTML. You'll have to use some JS library for this, which would replace your SELECT with some fancy DIV structure.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov ahh i thought it wouldn't be possible and thanks for clarifying this ... hopefully helps others in the future ... thanks!